# Count of the occurrence in the list for a given value

Tags: pandas, count

I have a data frame which has ***ids***, some ***code*** value,***code_name*** and a ***list_of_ids*** is a list of ***id***s .

```
id code   code_name  list_of_ids
1  AB111  apple      [5,2,3,4]
2  AB222  pear       [3,4]
3  AB333  banana     [1]
4  AB111  apple      []
5  AB222  pear       [2,6,4]
6  AB333  banana     [1,3,5]
7  AB333  banana     [1,3,6]
```

I'm trying to get a count of ids from the ***list_of_ids*** where ***id*** from the list   has the same ***code_name*** as a value in ***id*** column.

Thanks.
The desired output is to get the count. Column for_explanation is added to display only

```
id code   code_name  for_explanation            count
1  AB111  apple      [pear,pear,banana,apple]   1
2  AB222  pear       [banana,apple]             0
3  AB333  banana     [apple]                    0
4  AB111  apple      []                         0
5  AB222  pear       [pear,banana,apple]        0
6  AB333  banana     [apple,banana,pear]        0
7  AB333  banana     [apple,banana,banana]      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
s = df.set_index('id')['code_name']

df['count'] = [sum(1 for i in l if s.get(i)==c)
               for c,l in zip(df['code_name'], df['list_of_ids'])]
```

Or `explode` and `groupby`:

```
s = df.set_index('id')['code_name']

df['count'] = (df
   .explode('list_of_ids')
   .groupby(level=0)
   .apply(lambda d: d['list_of_ids'].map(s).eq(d['code_name']).sum())
)
```

output:

```
   id   code code_name   list_of_ids  count
0   1  AB111     apple  [5, 2, 3, 4]      1
1   2  AB222      pear        [3, 4]      0
2   3  AB333    banana           [1]      0
3   4  AB111     apple            []      0
4   5  AB222      pear     [2, 6, 4]      1
5   6  AB333    banana     [1, 3, 5]      1
6   7  AB333    banana     [1, 3, 6]      2
```